# How to authorize a python script to POST object to ParseServer

Tags: python, parse-platform, python-requests

I have a python script running on a chron job that synchronizes a Parse class with another database. I am using the REST API with Python Requests. My Parse Server install doesn't have a REST_API Key so I am trying to use the MasterKey but I get permission denied to create the object when I post. Here is what I have:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers={"X-Parse-Master-Key":"d1f76c19-3100-11ea-8f8e-005056051910"}, json=data)
```

If I open up the Class to write permission on the Public User the objects get created so I know the fundamentals of my code function. Is it perhaps better to create a User/Role for this?

Comment: What is the error message that you have? Do you have any trigger added to this class?

Comment: I get “permission denied to create object”. No triggers have been created for that class.

Comment: I think you are missing the X-Parse-Application-Id header. Does your app have one?

Comment: I have the application id as well, I just didn't include it for security reasons.

Comment: Can you share what do you have in the vars `url` and `data`?

Comment: URL=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/parse/classes/business

Comment: DATA= {'phone_number': '', 'city': 'Burnaby', 'rating': 0, 'chain': None,  'country': 'CA', 'state': 'BC', 'postal_code': '', 'business_type': 'restaurant', 'address': '102 - 33640 South Fraser Way', 'business_name': '2 Scoops', 'corp': None, 'location': {'latitude': 0.0, '__type': 'GeoPoint', 'longitude': 0.0}}

Comment: Your request looks right and you should be able to create a new object by sending the master key. Would you mind to also share your parse server version, settings and also your `business` class schema?